# Javascript validation error

Tags: javascript, validation

I have written the following code in html and the javascript file is also embedded below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="admin.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
</head>
<BODY>
<div class="adminnav" id="adminnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Insert</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="addcourse.html">Insert Course</a></li>
<li><a href="addstudent.html">Insert Student</a></li>
<li><a href="addteacher.html">Insert Teacher</a></li>
<li><a href="addsubject.html">Insert Subject</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="addcourse" >
<form name="course" onSubmit='return validcourse()' method="POST">
Course Name:
  <input type="text" name="coursename" id="cname" /><br>
Duration:<input type="text" name="cd"/>
<br>
Course Id:<input name="cid" type="text" /><br>
<input  type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><input type="reset" name="coursereset">
</form>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

common.js

```
function validcourse()
{
    var course_name=document.course.coursename;
    var course_duration=document.course.cd;
    var course_id=document.course.cid;

    if(course_name_valid(course_name))
    {
        {
            if(course_duration_valid(course_duration))
            {
                if(course_id_valid(cid))
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

function course_name_valid(course_name)
{
    var letters=/^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(course_name.value.match(letters))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Course name must have alphabets only");
        course_name.focus();
        return false;

    }
}

function course_duration_valid(course_duration)
{
    var letters=/^[1-9]+$/;
    if(cd.value.match(letters))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {   
        alert("Course Duration can have numbers only");
        course_duration.focus();    
        retun false;
    }   


}

function course_id_valid(course_id)
{
    var letters=/^[0-9a-zA-z]+$/;
    if(course_id.value.match(letters))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Course ID must have character and numeric values only');
        course_id.focus();
        return false;           
    }
}
```

My problem is that nothing is happening no error messages are given.
Error messages are given only for course name but not for course duration and course id?

Here is a link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amolkarale/aTfq6/1/

Comment: Put an alert at the top of your js and see if that executes. I suspect you are calling the wrong file.

Comment: I am calling common.js file which contains the code for validation.You can check the script tag.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle and update to post the link - much easier to debug that way

Comment: ok in a while i will do it

Comment: ok here is a link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amolkarale/aTfq6/1/

Comment: I realized that jsfiddle isn't the best place to debug live `document.` references - so I had to do it the old-fashioned way: copy-pasting your code :)

Comment: Thanks sudipta my code is running now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `validcourse`.  Add a `return true;` and `return false;` in there, to either let the submission continue or stop the submission from happening:

```
function validcourse()
{
    var course_name=document.course.coursename;
    var course_duration=document.course.cd;
    var course_id=document.course.cid;

    if(course_name_valid(course_name))
    {
        {
            if(course_duration_valid(course_duration))
            {
                if(course_id_valid(cid))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: I have tried man but it is not working still validations are not taking place

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the first line inside `validcourse`?  Just to see if your function ever gets executed?

Comment: You don't "write" breakpoints, you "set" them in your browser's debugger.  In Chrome for example: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a syntax error in your third function`course_duration_valid(course_duration)`

```
retrun false;
```

should be:

```
return false;
```

Comment: ya spelling mistake i have made it return

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I got your stuff to work. Here are the changes needed:

First, object references need to be cleaner in your DOM

```
var course_name=document.getElementById("cname");
var course_duration=document.getElementById("cd");
var course_id=document.getElementById("cid");
```

As you can see, the elements need to have their individual ids.

```
Course Name:
<input type="text" name="coursename" id="cname" /><br>
Duration:
<input type="text" name="cd" id="cd"/><br>
Course Id:
<input name="cid" type="text" id="cid" /><br>
```

Finally, the `retrun` needed to be corrected, as already pointed out by @Steve